# Can AppVeyor do auto publishing of nuget packages only for specific branch?

Tags: nuget, appveyor

In AppVeyor CI, if you enable automatic NuGet packaging (Settings -> Build -> Automatic Packaging), it publishes packages on every build, including builds of branches.

Is it possible to have it automatic but restrict it just to `master` branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [conditional build configuration](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/branches/#conditional-build-configuration). Here is simplified appveyor.yml example:

```
-
    version: 1.0.0.{build}-{branch}

    branches:
      only:
        - master

    build:
      publish_nuget: true
      verbosity: minimal  

-
    version: 1.0.0.{build}-{branch}

    build:
      publish_nuget: false
      verbosity: minimal
```

Thank you,

Ilya.